# How to duplicate inline objects to live?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I am new to Django CMS. I created a plugin with inlines.
When I save the plugin and when I publish the page the model gets duplicated but the inline objects are not getting duplicated.

Is there any way to do this? I want my inline objects also to save in live objects when I publish the page.

Comment: Give us some code.

Comment: Thanks deathangel908 for the reply. I got the result. I made a small mistake in my model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a `copy_relations` method on your plugin. The documentation is [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations), but essentially the functionality works like this;

```
class ArticlePluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        # Before copying related objects from the old instance, the ones
        # on the current one need to be deleted. Otherwise, duplicates may
        # appear on the public version of the page
        self.associated_item.all().delete()

        for associated_item in oldinstance.associated_item.all():
            # instance.pk = None; instance.pk.save() is the slightly odd but
            # standard Django way of copying a saved model instance
            associated_item.pk = None
            associated_item.plugin = self
            associated_item.save()


class AssociatedItem(models.Model):
    plugin = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticlePluginModel,
        related_name="associated_item"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the result. I made a small mistake.